# Xcode 8 Storyboard Grid?

Tags: grid, storyboard, interface-builder, xcode8

Is there any way I can show a grid on my storyboard to align my view controllers easier? Ive seen a couple old posts about this however none of which seem to be the answer for the current version of Xcode (Xcode 8). One post said that there was a "Snap To Grid" option under Editor -> Canvas but I couldn't find it.